# Tab Sectioned in Recyclerview which is in NestedScrollview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-tabs, sections, android-nestedscrollview

I am developing the application which having same functionality like if we have a menu which have category having Starters, Main Course and Desert in tabs and as I scroll recyclerview visible category should be selected in tab and if I select any tab it scould scroll to that section. It is a mixture of section tab, recyclerview, and nested scrollview.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using `ViewPager`, `BottomNavigationView` or anything else?

Comment: @Girish No. Bottom Navigation does not require for this

Comment: @android_sh Even after these many years. Did you get any solution for this?